# iron-flex-layout isn't getting applied on main document

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

`iron-flex-layout` isn't getting applied. can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">

    <link rel="import" href="components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <style is="custom-style"> 
      body { margin: 0; height: 100vh; @apply(--layout-horizontal); @apply(--layout-center);} 
      body div#utilitiesContainer {  @apply(--layout-horizontal);width:60%; height:auto; height:400px; padding:10px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#000000;@apply(--layout-self-center);}
      body paper-button {@apply(--layout-flex);}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body unresolved>
    <paper-button raised>Raised button</paper-button>
    <div id="utilitiesContainer">
    </div>
  </body>
```

i'm using the 2.0 preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polymer2.0 `is` is not available as most of the browsers did not agree on it. So in order to use `custom-style` you'll have to wrap `style` tag inside `custom-style` tag

```
<custom-style>
  <style>
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

Also, you have missed `include` attribute in your style tag.

Here are some references for you

- [Custom-style](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#examples)
- [Shared-styles(include)](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#share-styles-between-elements)